# Total mystery - iOS methods execute after random delay

Tags: iphone, ios, random, delay

I have the variant of the following codes, triggered by a user input.

```
NSLog(@"WHY YOU iOS!!!");
[scanButton setSelected:YES];
[overlayImageView setImage:image];
[overlayView setHidden:YES];
```

The thing is that the above routine executes with seemingly random delay from five seconds to more than a minute.

Sometimes, **they don't execute at all, except, mysteriously, the NSLog method.** If I set a breakpoint at the NSLog line, it just executes immediately and I can see "WHY YOU ..." printed out in the console. However, even though the debugger runs smoothly past the below three lines without errors or warnings, the effect of the the next three lines takes place after random delay, or infinite delay. What's wrong? How could it be possible that they have random delay?

I suspected that UI part of Cocoa SDK suspends due to my poor program design or whatever, but even during the random delay, other buttons and functionalities work so fine, while the effect of setImage takes place suddenly in 47.2 seconds. What's wrong with iOS, or with me?

What confounds me more is that the above exact routine works fine without delay if the image parameter (UIImage*) comes from a different source. If that's the case, we can attribute the cause of the problem to the image, however, why do scanButton and overlayView also respond with the same delay, even though they have nothing to do with the image? Total mystery to me.

Comment: Nothing's wrong with iOS (well, a lot is wrong with iOS, but probably not this part). Please show more code-- where and how is this code being run, and what comes after it?

Comment: One thing I have learnt in coding is any mystery is possible. And it seems like a mystery because you are ignoring several moving parts. If you put all the parts together, you unravel the mystery. Its called debugging!

Comment: @mbh Right. I just solved the problem and found that the source of the mystery was my ignorance, not the codes, or the way compilers work. They are no way mysterious as they are just deterministic automata. The bug was in my head. Now, I should start debugging my head to debug the actual codes. Anyway, thanks for your insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea on whats going on, as there is almost no hint in the code that you've provided, but why you dont try something like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        NSLog(@"WHY YOU iOS!!!");
        [scanButton setSelected:YES];
        [overlayImageView setImage:image];
        [overlayView setHidden:YES];

        [overlayImageView setNeedsDisplay];
        [overlayImageView setNeedsLayout];

        [scanButton setNeedsDisplay];
        [scanButton setNeedsLayout];

        [overlayView setNeedsDisplay];
        [overlayView setNeedsLayout];

});
```

Basically ensure always to update de UI in the main thread (in case that you're using a background thread) and set the UI controls as needed to be redrawn.

Comment: When you have UI-specific functions that aren't responding promptly, the cause is almost guaranteed to be that you're calling them on a background thread.  I think @Ecarrion's got the right answer here.

Comment: I will give it a try and report you back. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much. You are my hero. The random delay has been caused by a custom queue. When the above routine has been called from the method aligned on the queue, it followed the sequence of the custom queue, rather than the main queue, and responded to user actions with random delays. I just solved the problem and committed the code to our git repo, with the URL address to your answer. Thanks again.